# Area of a section of the cylinder bounded by two planes

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

> Compute the area of the region on the cylinder $x^2+y^2=R^2$ bounded by the planes $z=mx$ and $z=nx$ where $z\ge 0, m>n>0.$
>
> source: Demidovich, task 2214

**My attempt:**

I considered the following injective and continuously differentiable map $F:Q=[0,1]^2\to\Bbb R^3$ given by $F(u,v)=(R\cos(\pi u),R\sin(\pi u),R(n+(m-n)v)\cos(\pi u))$ in order to use the formula $$\nu(F)=\int_Q\sqrt{\det\nabla F(\boldsymbol u)^T\nabla F(\boldsymbol u)}d\boldsymbol u.$$

I get the following:

$$\nabla F(u,v)=\begin{bmatrix}-R\pi\sin(\pi u)&0\\ R\pi\cos(\pi u)&0\\ -R\pi(n+(m-n)v)\sin(\pi u)& R(m-n)\cos(\pi u)\end{bmatrix}.$$

So $$\begin{aligned}\nabla F(u,v)^T\nabla F(u,v)&=\begin{bmatrix}-R\pi\sin(\pi u)& R\pi\cos(\pi u)&-R\pi(n+(m-n)v)\sin(\pi u)\\0&0& R(m-n)\cos(\pi u)\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}-R\pi\sin(\pi u)&0\\ R\pi\cos(\pi u)&0\\ -R\pi(n+(m-n)v)\sin(\pi u)& R(m-n)\cos(\pi u)\end{bmatrix}\\&=\begin{bmatrix}R^2\pi^2(1+(n+(m-n)v)^2\sin^2(\pi u))&-R^2\pi(n+(m-n)v)\sin(\pi u)\cos(\pi u)\\-R^2\pi(n+(m-n)v)\sin(\pi u)\cos(\pi u)& R^2(m-n)^2\cos^2(\pi u)\end{bmatrix}\end{aligned}$$ and $$\begin{aligned}\det\nabla F(u,v)^T\nabla F(u,v)&=R^4\pi^2(m-n)^2\cos^2(\pi u)+ R^4\pi^2(n+(m-n)v)\sin^2(\pi u)\cos^2(\pi u)-R^4\pi^2(n+(m-n)v)^2\sin^2(\pi u)\cos^2(\pi u)\\&=R^4\pi^2(m-n)^2\cos^2(\pi u)\\\implies \sqrt{\det\nabla F(u,v)^T F(u,v)}&= R^2\pi|\cos(\pi u)|\end{aligned}$$ and finally, I obtained the integral $$\begin{aligned}\nu(F)&=\int_0^1\int_0^1R^2\pi|\cos(\pi u)|dudv\\&=R^2\pi\left(\int_0^{1/2}\cos(\pi u)du-\int_{1/2}^1\cos(\pi u)\right)\\&=R^2\pi\left(\frac{\sin(\pi u)}\pi\Big|_0^{1/2}-\frac{\sin(\pi u)}\pi\Big|_{1/2}^1\right)\\&=2R^2(m-n),\end{aligned}$$ but, in the book, the solution is $4R^2(m-n),$ which is twice of mine. I checked again the condition $z\ge 0$ and I can't find my mistake. Is there anything wrong and is there anything illegitimate with the procedure itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s correct. To verify, integrate the area below in cylindrical coordinates
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} (z_m -z_n)R d\theta
= R^2 (m-n)\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos\theta \ d\theta=2R^2(m-n)
$$
where $z_k = k x =kR\cos\theta$.

Comment: Thank you! I've now noticed I looked the angle from $0$ to $\pi$ instead of from $-\frac\pi2$ to $\frac\pi2,$ but that didn't affect the result.